# Why do I need to use Math.floor on my array for rock, paper, scissors game

Tags: javascript

```
var arrayName = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissor'];

var selection = arrayName[Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayName.length)];

alert('The computer chose:' + selection);
```

Comment: Because without `Math.floor` you would get numbers like `1.28`, `0.32`, and `2.94356`. You need to make sure you only get `0`, `1`, or `2`.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` returns a fraction, and when you multiply that by the length of the array, you'll get a number with decimal places in it. But array indexes have to be whole numbers. `Math.floor()` discards the fraction after the decimal place.

Comment: Gotcha, the index part was where I was getting confused. Thanks for clearing that up for me!